# In C++, how would I program an exception that catches any number over 10?

Tags: c++

I know this sounds really simple but...

I'm just doing a simple guessing game and I'm trying to use try/throw/catch to handle the error of an input of over 10. I don't think my teacher wants a simple

```
if(x>10) 
{ 
//do this 
}
```

instead I think she wants us to do:

```
if(x>10) 
{ 
throw DONT_KNOW_WHAT_TO_PUT ; 
} 

catch(DONT_KNOW_WHAT_TO_PUT) 
{ 
//do this 
}
```

How do I do it with the throw and catch?
Does throw and catch only work with Exceptions and not just random throws?

Edit:  I simply just want to throw an error if an input is over 10.  Then I catch that error and output that the number is out of the range I want.

And trust me, I would NEVER want to do something like this, but my teacher's instructions are so unclear that I don't know if she wants me to just get all inputs that would be invalid using only try/catch/throw or not.

Comment: The title implies testing `x>10` at the catch, but the question implies testing `x>10` before the throw.  Which do you want?

Comment: `throw std::runtime_error(<reason string>)` and `catch(std::exception const&)`

Comment: 1st off: Don't use exceptions to control program logic!!

Comment: You can even throw an `int` if you want, and `catch` it later, but it's not a good idea to use `throw/catch` in branches.

Comment: You also need `try { ` and `}` surrounding the code you are throwing from

Comment: In my experience, teachers like when you ask for clarification and would be happy to provide it. It shows you've thought about the problem/solution in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

if you really wanted to be impressive

```
 #include <stdexcep>

 . . . .


 throw std:range_error ("YOUR MESSAGE HERE") ;

 . . . . 

try
{

}
catch (std::exception &error)
{
    cerr << errror.what () << endl ;
}
```

Comment: catch by const reference please.  Or at _least_ by reference!

Comment: There isn't a `try` block in this sample. Also, why don't you just catch the `std::range_error` instead of `std::exception` (by reference of course)?

Comment: 1) I edited it to include one. 2) std::range_error is derived from std::exception. This catches everything.. You could make it range_error if you wanted to perform different actions for different exceptions.